# VSCODE Extension stacked Output in Problems Section

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Can someone give me a hint why vscode is stacking the outputs in the problems section when ran multiple times (in our self made vscode extension, from the same textfile)?

[image: first run]

[image: second run]

**class definition:**

```
import {  Uri, languages, Range, Diagnostic, Position, DiagnosticCollection } from "vscode";

export class ProblemHelper{

   public rangeObj: Range | undefined; 
   public  problemObj: Diagnostic | undefined;
   public problemEntries: Array<Diagnostic> = [];

   //public static diagnosticCollection: DiagnosticCollection;
   constructor(actDocument: Uri| undefined,message: string, severity: number){

     console.log("problemhelper const 0 " + this.problemEntries.length);
     this.rangeObj = new Range(new Position(1,1),new Position(1,1) );
     this.problemObj = new Diagnostic(this.rangeObj,message,severity );
     this.problemObj.source = actDocument?.fsPath;
     this.problemEntries.push(this.problemObj);
     console.log("problemhelper const 1 " + this.problemEntries.length);      
  }

  public  setProblems(actDocument: Uri, coll: DiagnosticCollection, mess: string, sev: number) {
      this.problemEntries.forEach(e => {
          if (this.problemObj?.message === e.message) { 
             return;
          }
      });
      this.rangeObj = new Range(new Position(1,1),new Position(1,1) );
      this.problemObj = new Diagnostic(this.rangeObj,mess,sev );
      this.problemEntries.push(this.problemObj);
      console.log("problemhelper const 3 "  + this.problemEntries.length);
      coll.set(actDocument,this.problemEntries);
      console.log("problemhelper const 4 " + coll.get(actDocument)?.length);
      //ProblemHelper.diagnosticCollection!.set(actDocument,ProblemHelper.problemEntries);
  }

  public deleteProblems(actDocument: Uri | undefined, coll: DiagnosticCollection) {
       console.log("in delete before " + this.problemEntries.length);
       coll.delete(actDocument!);
       this.problemEntries = [];
       console.log("in delete after " + this.problemEntries.length);
       //coll.dispose();
   }

}
```

**called with:**

```
const diagnosticCollection = languages.createDiagnosticCollection(window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri.fsPath);
let temp = new ProblemHelper(window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri,"test", 0);
temp.deleteProblems(window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri,diagnosticCollection);

temp.setProblems(window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri!,diagnosticCollection,"test1",1);
    
temp.setProblems(window.activeTextEditor?.document.uri!,diagnosticCollection,"test222",2);
console.log("end");
```

Output in debug console (screenshots are from "EXTENSION DEVELOPMENT HOST", as can be seen the correct amount of entries is printed out, but it is getting stacked up every time):

```
problemhelper const 0 0
problemhelper const 1 1
in delete before 1
in delete after 0
problemhelper const 3 1
problemhelper const 4 1
problemhelper const 3 2
problemhelper const 4 2
end
problemhelper const 0 0
problemhelper const 1 1
in delete before 1
in delete after 0
problemhelper const 3 1
problemhelper const 4 1
problemhelper const 3 2
problemhelper const 4 2
end
```

VSCODE Version: 1.66.0 (WIN 10)

Thank you!

Comment: do you create a new set of objects for each run, if so ==> don't

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much you are right, i made a new class twice, so i run this at extension startup, and do clear() instead of delete(xx). Now i can move forward.